# Creating a close button for the UI to close the form is freezing and stopping my app

Tags: c#

I am building a style on C# for the apps I am building but I am having difficulties with making the close button close the form which it is currently placed in. When pressed it freezes the entire software and every open page.

This is the code for the close button.

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) //Close button On click button
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        //Environment.Exit(0);
        if (FindForm().WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            FindForm().Close();

        }
    }
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) //The Minimize button code
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        switch (FindForm().WindowState)
        {
            case FormWindowState.Normal:
                FindForm().WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                break;
            case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                FindForm().WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Posted the code for the edit button so I can show how a similar code would work

And it works. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the close button.

I expect the output of the code is to close the window which the close button is dragged in.

The close button looks like this:

https://prnt.sc/ploopn

But when clicked the entire app, no matter how many pages are open, it freezes.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT: This is all the code of the Close button

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlatUI
{
    public class FlatClose : Control
    {
    private MouseState State = MouseState.None;
    private int x;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        State = MouseState.Over;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        State = MouseState.Down;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        State = MouseState.None;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        State = MouseState.Over;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        x = e.X;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        //Environment.Exit(0);
        if (FindForm().WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            FindForm().Close();

        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        Size = new Size(18, 18);
    }

    [Category("Colors")]
    public Color BaseColor
    {
        get { return _BaseColor; }
        set { _BaseColor = value; }
    }

    [Category("Colors")]
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get { return _TextColor; }
        set { _TextColor = value; }
    }

    private Color _BaseColor = Color.FromArgb(168, 35, 35);
    private Color _TextColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 243, 243);

    public FlatClose()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        BackColor = Color.White;
        Size = new Size(18, 18);
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
        Font = new Font("Marlett", 10);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap B = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(B);

        Rectangle Base = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

        var _with3 = G;
        _with3.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        _with3.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        _with3.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        _with3.Clear(BackColor);

        //-- Base
        _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_BaseColor), Base);

        //-- X
        _with3.DrawString("r", Font, new SolidBrush(TextColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), Helpers.CenterSF);

        //-- Hover/down
        switch (State)
        {
            case MouseState.Over:
                _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, Color.White)), Base);
                break;
            case MouseState.Down:
                _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, Color.Black)), Base);
                break;
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
        G.Dispose();
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(B, 0, 0);
        B.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can leave it with no action there and can do it on every form something like ```this.close();``` but I want to make it easier

Comment: that's part of the ```using System.Windows.Forms;``` to my knowledge. I am not entirely sure what exactly it does exactly, but I've seen some tutorial weeks ago and been using it since. (I know its not the smartest thing to do but I am still doing it)

Comment: Try to place these buttons in a new default WinForm with nothing else to examine their functionalities. If that close button still freezes the application, then something wrong with it. If not, then check the code of your styled form. Make sure your controls are not trying to access disposed objects whether in their paint and/or the clean up routines. Good luck.

Comment: @BTEK Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman done. included the entire code for the close button. Should I also include the entire code for the minimize button?

Comment: Your control should be just raising a click event.  The form hosting your control should be listening to that event.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I replaced the example with a version that uses forms created in the designer.**

Example flatwindowcontrols : start : -------------------------

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class FlatMinimize : FlatWindowControlBase
{
    public FlatMinimize() : base("0", Window_Action.Minimize) { }
}

public class FlatMaximize : FlatWindowControlBase
{
    public FlatMaximize() : base("1", Window_Action.Maximize) { }

}

public class FlatClose : FlatWindowControlBase
{
    public FlatClose() : base("r", Window_Action.Close) { }
}


public class FlatWindowControlBase : Control
{
    private enum MouseState
    {
        None,
        Over,
        Down
    }

    public enum Window_Action
    {
        Minimize,
        Maximize,
        Close
    }

    private Window_Action _WindowAction;
    public Window_Action WindowAction { get => _WindowAction; set => _WindowAction = value; }

    private string _ButtonGlyph;
    public string ButtonGlyph { get => _ButtonGlyph; set => _ButtonGlyph = value; }

    private MouseState State = MouseState.None;

    public StringFormat CenterSF;

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e) { State = MouseState.Over; Invalidate(); }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) { State = MouseState.Down; Invalidate(); }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) { State = MouseState.None; Invalidate(); }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) { State = MouseState.Over; Invalidate(); }

    protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e) => Invalidate();

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Form buffer = FindForm();

        switch (WindowAction)
        {
            case Window_Action.Minimize:
                buffer.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                break;
            case Window_Action.Maximize:
                buffer.WindowState = ((buffer.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized) ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal);
                break;
            case Window_Action.Close:
                buffer.Close();
                break;
        }
    }

    private Color _BaseColor = Color.FromArgb(168, 35, 35);
    [Category("Colors"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "168, 35, 35")]
    public Color BaseColor
    {
        get => _BaseColor;
        set { _BaseColor = value; }
    }

    private Color _TextColor = Color.FromArgb(243, 243, 243);
    [Category("Colors"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "243, 243, 243")]
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get => _TextColor;
        set { _TextColor = value; }
    }

    public FlatWindowControlBase(string inButtonGlyph, Window_Action inWindowAction)
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        BackColor = Color.White;
        Size = new Size(18, 18); //You were also doing this in the OnResize() event.  If you want to restrict the size of the control, just override SetBoundsCore().
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
        Font = new Font("Marlett", 10);
        //CenterSF = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center }; //Centers Horizontally
        CenterSF = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center }; //Centers Horizontally and Vertically

        ButtonGlyph = inButtonGlyph;
        WindowAction = inWindowAction;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //All these versions, produce the same output

        //Original version
        //{
        //    Bitmap B = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        //    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(B);

        //    Rectangle Base = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

        //    var _with3 = G;
        //    _with3.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //    _with3.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        //    _with3.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        //    _with3.Clear(BackColor);

        //    //-- Base
        //    _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(_BaseColor), Base);

        //    //-- X
        //    _with3.DrawString("r", Font, new SolidBrush(TextColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), CenterSF);

        //    //-- Hover/down
        //    switch (State)
        //    {
        //        case MouseState.Over:
        //            _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, Color.White)), Base);
        //            break;
        //        case MouseState.Down:
        //            _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, Color.Black)), Base);
        //            break;
        //    }

        //    base.OnPaint(e);
        //    G.Dispose();
        //    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(B, 0, 0);
        //    B.Dispose();
        //}

        //Version not using a Bitmap
        {
            Rectangle Base = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

            e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BaseColor), Base);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ButtonGlyph, Font, new SolidBrush(TextColor), Base, CenterSF); //-- X
            if (State != MouseState.None) { e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, ((State == MouseState.Over) ? Color.White : Color.Black))), Base); } //-- Hover/down
        }

        //Version using a Bitmap
        //{
        //    //Why are you creating a bitmap and drawing that?  You can't just draw on controls surface?
        //    using (Bitmap B = new Bitmap(Width, Height))
        //    using (Graphics _with3 = Graphics.FromImage(B))
        //    {
        //        Rectangle Base = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

        //        //Not going to tell the difference.  So, I disable them.
        //        //_with3.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        //        //_with3.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        //        //_with3.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        //        _with3.Clear(BackColor);

        //        _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BaseColor), Base); //-- Base

        //        _with3.DrawString(ButtonGlyph, Font, new SolidBrush(TextColor), Base, CenterSF); //-- X

        //        if (State != MouseState.None) { _with3.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, ((State == MouseState.Over) ? Color.White : Color.Black))), Base); } //-- Hover/down

        //        //base.OnPaint(e);
        //        //e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        //        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(B, 0, 0);
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Example flatwindowcontrols : end : ---------------------------

Example : start --------------------------------

Program.cs : start : ---------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    static class Form_Helper
    {
        public static void Generic_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0) { Application.ExitThread(); }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1,
                                HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

        class MultipleFormsOpen : ApplicationContext
        {
            public MultipleFormsOpen()
            {
                Form1 mainform = new Form1();

                mainform.MouseDown += (s, me) =>
                {
                    if (me.Button == MouseButtons.Left) { ReleaseCapture(); SendMessage(mainform.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0); }
                };

                mainform.Show();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MultipleFormsOpen());
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs : end : ---------------------------

form1.cs : start : ---------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent();

            FormClosed += Form_Helper.Generic_FormClosed;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 SecondaryForm = new Form2();
            SecondaryForm.FormClosed += Form_Helper.Generic_FormClosed;
            SecondaryForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

form1.cs : end : ---------------------------

Edit 5 : end :  ----------------------------------------

Comment: this does actually work far better than the one I am working on. But it actually closes all open forms. how do I prevent that?

Comment: Closes all forms?  That doesn't sound right.  K.  Let me look at, after a bit.  Making food for my daughter and stuff.

Comment: wait I think the code is right but might be something with my app. something I might have not checked right. created a test project and put 2 forms, if main form is closed the other form is too.. how to fix this?

Comment: Added an example.  Not sure.  May need to see how the forms are being created.

Comment: You said if you close the main form ... If your main form created these forms or if you're talking about "Form1" which is the startup form for that app ... it WILL close all the forms and the app itself.   Form1 is created in Program.cs and once it's closed your app closes.

Comment: how to prevent that? I don't really remember... but i remember doing it before

Comment: If you want to send a test app to me and instructions on what you're doing, i.e. I click on this and it closes everything .. I can take a look at it.  If you're talking about the "Form1" scenario, why do you not want it open?  Do you ever want it open?  Does your scenario maybe call for a systray app, that opens up these secondary forms and that's all you want to display.  You can send an email to my github username at hotmail.com

Comment: We get it working, I'll update my answer on here.  So, others can see.

Comment: I meant, my email is my stackoverflow username at hotmail.com

Comment: Update the Test Example, to the no Form1 scenario.  It creates three Forms and doesn't close the Application until all the forms are closed.  If this isn't what you want, email and give me details on what you want.  I'll help you get it working.

Comment: I don't remember why the software closes after closing the first form. aka Form 1. I remember I changed something in the settings and then would do something like this.dispose() if wanted to close the form.

Comment: I updated the Control, to do Minimize, Maximize, and Close.

Comment: mate, the code is amazing, but your first attempt fixed it, so thank you. now my question is why closing the Form1 closes the entire application. I want the application to close when there's no standing form open. How can I do that?

Comment: The above example will do that.  It'll stay open until all forms are closed.  The code that gets assigned to the FormClosed() event, takes care of that for you.  This was the only way I could think of, to accomplish this.

Comment: not really. code works perfectly but not what i want. I remember it being something like this https://prnt.sc/po4l20

Comment: That looks like a VB .NET properties screen.  VB did or does have some other application settings you can set.  One is something that tells the app not to close until all forms are closed.  In C#, you have to alter your Program.cs like I presented to you.  For example: If you wanted Form2 to be your startup Form, you'd change Application.Run(new Form1) to Application.Run(new Form2).  If you send me your project and details of how you want it to work, I can probably get it to work like you want.

Comment: Note:  I forgot to mention, you can have your Main() elsewhere and specify in your setting, where it's located.  I said you HADE to alter Program.cs.  No, that's just the general / default location of your Main().

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply but I've been traveling. I want the form 1 to be the main form, but when I close it I dont want to close other forms too. how can i prevent that? your example kinda works for haivng multiple forms but it totally  ruins my forms and the designs I made so is not really useful

Comment: Added a different example. It seems to do exactly what you're asking.  I can create multiple form2 forms and then close them or form1 at any time.  This code is essentially exactly what I gave last time.  Let me know.

Comment: Did I ever mention that every form you create, including Form1, has to execute the custom FormClose() event, which does the "Application.OpenForms.Count" check?